# CEFSharp write in session storage

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I want to perform automatic login to an SPA through my WPF app which uses CEFSharp to load web pages. In order to do that, I use an API to receive a token. What I need to do is store this token in the browser's session storage. Is it possible with CEFSharp?

Comment: There is no `API` access, you could probably execute some javascript. See the `FAQ` if you need more details.

Comment: You can of course create a cookie though the `API`

Comment: Yeah I figured that out. I'm running this javascript: "sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'value');" but nothing is written in the session storage. If I run it after I initially display the screen, the value is written. My setup is very simple. I have a user control with the browser and the datacontext is bound with a viewmodel which exposes the Address. The order of running things is create the user control, set the datacontext, run the javascript, set the address in the viewmodel and activate a prism region with the user control. But no joy.

Comment: Have you read the `FAQ` in regards to when you can execute `javascript`? You have to wait for the underlying `V8` engine to initialize.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction. It seems I will need to render offscreen, perform the login and reload it to set up the page for first use. Does CEFSharp support render something offscreen and then use the same control to render in a WPF window?

Comment: You would have to also include the `CefSharp.OffScreen` project. Easiest option would be to overlay a loading screen over the top. Or even keep the browser very small, a size of `1x1` may be enough to initialize and render correctly.

Comment: There maybe another option, you could possibly inherit `ChromiumWebBrowser` and manually create the browser. You'll have to sort work out the details yourself if you choose this path. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L893

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I will try to go down the subclassing route.